# Can I somehow dock the searchbox (ctrl +f) or create a new searchbox in the top menu in Google Sheets so that it is always visible?

Tags: search, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been searching for a while now but I cannot find an answer to the following question; Is it possible to dock or show the searchbox from Google Sheets somewhere so that it is always visible?
I have some experience with Google Apps Script so any solution from that perspective is also fine!

Ps. I can't use a `sidebar`.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that you can do to the Google Sheets UI via Google Apps Script is documented in [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).

You have no control over Google's UI components, such as the Search & Replace dialog.

You *could* implement your own search dialog, and display it as a modeless dialog that would always be visible. If you've already looked into sidebar and found that didn't work for you, just replace your call to `showSidebar()` with [`showModelessDialog()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModelessDialog(Object,String)).

Comment: Ah that is a pretty nice solution, thanks! It appears in the middle of my screen by default, is there a way to change it's position? :)

Comment: You can move it manually by clicking on the title and dragging the dialog. No way to position it programmatically, unfortunately.

Comment: Your self rolled search is guaranteed to be less good than the default. No offence intended.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jonathon, I am still going to try to create the search function since I have no other option.