# Can I reposition a modeless dialog in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

Using Google Apps Script, how can I position a modeless dialog?

Here my Code.gs function that opens the modeless dialog and renders an existing html file into it:

```
ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function sillyFunc() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("SillyFunc")
    .setWidth(600)
    .setHeight(500);
  ui.showModelessDialog(html, "Silly Func");
};
```

All this works fine, but the modeless dialog opens in the center of my browser. Is there any way that I can position it at creation time?

What I really want is to render the html file in my spreadsheet - it's a chart created via Google's Visualization API. As far as I was able to find out, this is not possible. The closest seems to be to use a modeless dialog instead.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987984/can-i-somehow-dock-the-searchbox-ctrl-f-or-create-a-new-searchbox-in-the-top), there is no way to position the `ModelessDialog` programmatically. But, you can move it manually by clicking the title and dragging the dialog. For more information about ModelessDialog, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodelessdialoguserinterface-title).